Drilled 3/4" hole through shortened stud above door, is that an issue?
I wanted to add a junction box on the outside of my garage and started drilling a hole from the outside. For aesthetic reasons I chose to drill above a door (centered horizontally with the door). I drilled a 3/4" hole in my external plaster wall.  I hit wood so I used a 3/4" spade bit and drilled through.  I had a Romex cable that I pulled through the hole for the junction box.
However, I just happened to drill right through a short stud!  My question is, should I be concerned that this will compromise something structurally in my garage?
Here's a picture from the inside.


Please consider alternative terms for this component, such as "pin stud". The word "cripple" can be hurtful for those with physical impairment or those of shorter stature, to which the framing term refers. It's akin to calling a problematic tool "that cotton-picking thing", which hearkens to slavery and racism. The reference isn't apparent or important to everyone, but it's there.

@isherwood  Interesting point.  Searching I did find this reddit post of the same thing.  It seems at one did have some good alternative names.   https://www.reddit.com/r/Carpentry/comments/nw6p6w/different_term_for_cripples/   Pin stud search went far away from wall building.

Good point @isherwood.  I've corrected the terminology
